# Bright monitor for office with intense ambient sunlight

Tags: monitors

I am a software developer, recently moved to a new office with huge windows. There is so much sunlight that the regular monitor I have been provided with looks dark at 100% brightness. Is there a good 27' monitor with brightness similar to macbookpro retina, for example? It will be used with a mac mini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Dell S2719DM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079QRS43V)

This monitor is 27 inches, 2560 by 1440, and claims a brightness of 600 nits. This beats out even the brightest 500 nit Macbooks, and certainly the more common 350 or 400 nit ones. And it's only $350.

It's also fairly thin. It only has HDMI ports, but so does the Mac Mini, so no big deal.